# Custom effects not working

Tags: jquery

I made a custom effect method using `.animate()` method to get a better `slideUp` and `slideDown` method. [**Here's the result**](http://jsfiddle.net/W5qQF/)

The animation `moveUp` works but `moveDown` doesn't and I have to pass `fadeIn` in `.init()` call. I know that its because of this CSS,

```
.js-enabled form {
position: absolute;
top: -21px;
display: none;
}
```

as `fadeIn` removes `display: none;`

So, I changed the CSS to

```
/* top: -21px; */
/* display: none; */
top: -330px;  /* <-- Added later and everything stopped working */
```

[**Here's the result**](http://jsfiddle.net/W5qQF/1/)

Any ideas why its not working?

thanks for help !

**EDIT**

Found the problem, its in JS line 34

```
if (container.is(':hidden')) {
```

I changed it to

```
if (container.css('top') == -330) {
```

But still nothing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it.

`container.css('top')` returns a string (confirmed by using `console.log(typeof container.css('top'));`

So, changing the if condition to `container.css('top') === '-330px')` did the trick.

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/W5qQF/2/)